# How to determine the properties of a Scala class at runtime?

Tags: scala, reflection, runtime, introspection

I would like to programmatically determine all properties of a Scala class at runtime.  For instance, for the following Scala class I would like to determine that the methods `name1`, `name3`, `name4`, and `name5` are getters for properties of `A`:

```
class A(val name1: String, private val name2: String) {
  val name3 = ""
  var name4 = ""
  def name5 = ""
  def name6() = ""
}
```

Most of the work can be done with Java's reflection API.  Unfortunately I was not able to detect the difference between `name5` and `name6()`.  Therefore I started a next trial using the ScalaSigParser, but ScalaSig's flags for `name5` and `name6()` are unfortunately also the same.  Here is my code:

```
def gettersOf(clazz: Class[_]) = {
  for (ssig <- ScalaSigParser.parse(clazz))
  yield {
    ssig.symbols.toList.collect{
      case m: MethodSymbol => m
    }.filter(m => (m.symbolInfo.flags & 0xFFFFF) == 0x200)
  }
}

gettersOf(classOf[A]).get.foreach{m =>
  println(m.name + ": " + m)
}
```

As you can see in the following output both methods differ only in the `info` value:

```
name1: MethodSymbol(name1, owner=0, flags=28400200, info=22 ,None)
<init>: MethodSymbol(<init>, owner=0, flags=200, info=38 ,None)
name3: MethodSymbol(name3, owner=0, flags=8400200, info=45 ,None)
name4: MethodSymbol(name4, owner=0, flags=8000200, info=45 ,None)
name4_$eq: MethodSymbol(name4_$eq, owner=0, flags=8000200, info=54 ,None)
name5: MethodSymbol(name5, owner=0, flags=200, info=45 ,None)
name6: MethodSymbol(name6, owner=0, flags=200, info=66 ,None)
```

However, `info` does not seem to return static constants.  If you add another method to the class the `info` value of `name6` will change while there seems to be some stability:

- `name3`, `name4`, and `name5` have always the same `info` value
- `name6` and `name5` have always different `info` values

Does someone know the meaning of `info` and how one can use it to surely determine which kind of method it is?

Related questions:

- [How does Scala know the difference between “def foo” and “def foo()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130106/how-does-scala-know-the-difference-between-def-foo-and-def-foo)

Comment: Not an answer directly, but you are aware that Scala 2.10 is just around the corner and has the new reflection api?  You might try a milestone for that.

Comment: @BrianSmith: Thanks for the hint.  I would actually like to step over to Scala 2.10 immediately.  Unfortunately most of my dependencies are not yet available for 2.10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a reflection API of the coming Scala 2.10.

Here's how to get the properties of a type in 2.10.0-M6:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> typeOf[A].members.view.filter{_.isValue}.filter{!_.isMethod}.toList
res0: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = List(variable name4, value name3, value name2, value name1)
```

Unfortunately there's not much reading material on it yet. There are some answered questions on SO though. For instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586944/how-to-obtain-the-raw-datatype-of-a-parameter-of-a-field-that-is-specialized-in) question might be of interest to you. Also please check out [this](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2012/07/json-serialization-with-reflection-in.html) blogpost by Daniel Sobral.

Comment: Wow.  That simplifies the problem a lot.  I think I will step over to this solution once all my dependent libraries are compatible with Scala 2.10.

Comment: Unfortunately, runtime reflection will broken under multi-threading env.

Answer (score 3):

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
typeOf[A].members map (m => m -> m.typeSignature) collect { 
  case (m, nm: NullaryMethodType) => m 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.  Instead of using the primitive `info` value one can use the more informative `infoType` which seems to return a `NullaryMethodType` for all methods not having parenthesis:

```
def gettersOf(clazz: Class[_]) = {
  for (ssig <- ScalaSigParser.parse(clazz))
  yield {
    ssig.symbols.toList.collect {
      case m: MethodSymbol => m
    }.filter(m => (m.symbolInfo.flags & 0xFFFFF) == 0x200 && m.infoType.isInstanceOf[NullaryMethodType])
  }
}
```

In the end we get the desired result without `name6` and without the hidden `<init>` method:

```
name1: MethodSymbol(name1, owner=0, flags=28400200, info=22 ,None)
name3: MethodSymbol(name3, owner=0, flags=8400200, info=45 ,None)
name4: MethodSymbol(name4, owner=0, flags=8000200, info=45 ,None)
name5: MethodSymbol(name5, owner=0, flags=200, info=45 ,None)
```